# C++ Bug fixing: Hawaiian Pronunciation Program

Tags: c++, debugging

I am writing a C++ program that will show you how to pronounce a Hawaiian word.

Rules:

- p, k, h, l, m, n (Pronounced like the english versions.)
- w -start of word (Either pronounced as a w or a v sound.  We shall pronounce it as a w sound.)
- w -after the letter ‘a’ (Either pronounced as a w or a v sound.  We shall pronounce it as a w sound.)
- w -after ‘i’ or ‘e’ (Pronounced as a v sound.)
- w -after ‘u’ or o (Pronounced as a w sound.)

My progress: My program works, but there's a couple of bugs.

1. When I type "iwa", the pronunciation must be "ee-vah" but I'm
   getting "ee-wah".
2. My code is not ignoring whitespaces. So when I type "e komo mai", I want "eh koh-moh meye" but instead, I get "e komo mai is pronounced eh-eh-koh-moh-oh-meye".

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string convertToHawaiian(string input);
bool vowelGroup(char first, char next, string& replacement);
bool consonantGroup(char prevchar, char currchar, string& replacement);
bool singleVowel(char current, string& replacement);

int main() {
   // Declare my variables
   string userInput;
   string replacement;

   //cout << "Enter a hawaiian word to pronounce ==>";
   getline(cin,userInput);

   // For loop that will call my Consonant function
   // Call my Hawaiian function and put it
   // into pronunciation 
   replacement = convertToHawaiian(userInput);

   // if My initial input has a capital, the replacement
   // will keep the capital letter at the beginning
   if (isupper(userInput.at(0))) {
      replacement.at(0) = toupper(replacement.at(0));
   }

   // Get rid of the '-' character at the end of the string
   if (replacement.at(replacement.size() - 1) == '-') {
      replacement.pop_back();
   }

   cout << userInput << " is pronounced " << replacement << endl;

   return 0;
}

// My main function that will convert my input
// into the hawaiian pronunciation
string convertToHawaiian(string input) {
   char nextChar;
   string replacement = "";
   string result = "";

   // Iterate through my string to check for vowels,
   // vowelgroups and consonants.
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
      char character = input.at(i);
      character = tolower(character);

      if (i != input.size() - 1) {
         nextChar = input.at(i + 1);
         nextChar = tolower(nextChar);
      }
      if ((i != input.size() - 1) && (vowelGroup(character, nextChar, replacement))) {
         i++;
         result = result + replacement;
      }
      else if (singleVowel(character, replacement)) {
         result = result + replacement;
      }
      else {
         consonantGroup(character, nextChar, replacement);
         result = result + replacement;
      } 
   }
   return result;
}

bool vowelGroup (char first, char nextChar, string& result) {
   bool isVowel = true;
   if (first == 'a') {
      nextChar = tolower(nextChar);

      if ((nextChar == 'i') || (nextChar == 'e')) {
         result = "eye-";
      }
      else if ((nextChar == 'o') || (nextChar == 'u')) {
         result = "ow-";
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }     
   }
   else if (first == 'e') {
      nextChar = tolower(nextChar);

      if (nextChar == 'i') {
         result = "ay-";
      }
      else if (nextChar == 'u') {
         result = "eh-oo-";
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   else if (first == 'i') {
      nextChar = tolower(nextChar);

      if (nextChar == 'u') {
         result = "ew-";
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   else if (first == 'o') {
      nextChar = tolower(nextChar);

      if (nextChar == 'i') {
         result = "oy-";
      }
      else if (nextChar == 'u') {
         result = "ow-";
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   else if (first == 'u') {
      nextChar = tolower(nextChar);

      if (nextChar == 'i') {
         result = "ooey-";

      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   else {
      isVowel = false;
      return isVowel;
   }
   return isVowel;
}

// Check to verify consonants
bool consonantGroup(char character, char nextChar, string& replacement) {
   bool isConson = true;
   if ((character == 'p') || (character == 'k') || (character == 'h') || (character == 'l') || (character == 'm') || (character == 'n')){
      replacement = character;
      return isConson;
   }
   if ((character == 'w') && (nextChar == 'a')) {
      replacement = 'w';
      return isConson;
   }
   else if (((character == 'u') || (character == 'o')) && (nextChar == 'w')) {
      replacement = 'w';
      cout << "Not replacing w" << endl;
      return isConson;
   }
   else if (((character == 'i') || (character == 'e')) && (nextChar == 'w')) {
      replacement = 'v';
      return isConson;
   }
   else {
      isConson = false;
      return isConson;
   }
}

bool singleVowel(char current, string& result) {
   bool isVowel = true;
   if (current == 'a') {
      result = "ah-";
      return isVowel;
   }
   else if (current == 'e') {
      result = "eh-";
      return isVowel;
   }
   else if (current == 'i') {
      result = "ee-";
      return isVowel;
   }
   else if (current == 'o') {
      result = "oh-";
      return isVowel;
   }
   else if (current == 'u') {
      result = "oo-";
      return isVowel;
   }
   else {
      isVowel = false;
      return isVowel;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should be able to make your [mre] more minimal...

Comment: Please point out the output lines which should make the parts of the desired output "ee-vah" and the lines which **do** the parts of the undesired output "ee-wah".

Comment: In your undesired result "ee" is the `replacement` from `singleVowel` and the `result` from `consonantGroup`. The "w" is the `result` from `consonantGroup`. Both together are the `result` from `singleVowel`. The "ah-" is the `replacement` from `singleVowel`. Does that seem right to you? I am missing the special case treatment for "w".

Answer (score 0):

One of the more common sources of bugs is shared mutable state.
In your case, it is state shared between loop iterations.

The whitespace case is handled here:

```
else {
    consonantGroup(character, nextChar, replacement);
    result = result + replacement;
}
```

and in that case, `replacement` will be string "spilled over" from the previous iteration.

The remedy is very simple: declare `replacement` inside the loop instead.

You can solve the "iwa" problem if you stare at these lines until you spot the bug:

```
if ((character == 'w') && (nextChar == 'a')) {
    replacement = 'w';
```